# No sooner in present

Tags: present-tense

I know the meaning of "no sooner ", but I have found phrases constructions always in the past, for example:

> No sooner had the automated arm been raised than it went down and damaged the car.

Could you please tell me if this phrase can be formulated in the present tense to indicate something that usually happens?

Comment: Try googling for `"no sooner does"` or `"no sooner will"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special use is not just *'no sooner'*, but *'no sooner....than...'*.

It talks about two events (the 'tenses' don't matter) that occur one after another. In most of the cases, you see them occurring in the past. But present is also possible.

[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/no-sooner-does-something-happen-than-something-else-happens) has an entry for  *no sooner does something happen than something else happens*. But, the example is in the past tense.

However, it's possible to make a sentence in the present tense. Let me try -

> No sooner ***is*** the break over than the patrons enter the cinema-hall.

Comment: Perfect,I wasn't sure about it, and what about the passive form in the present? "No sooner is it raised than it goes down ". Is this possible?

Comment: It does not look proper to me. *"No sooner does it raise than it goes down"* probably... However, don't be too quick to accept this answer! Let other come. That's how things work here!